# Is there no clang linker in the cygwin package

Tags: clang, cygwin

I've installed clang in cygwin and wondered about that there is no linker in the folder?

How to get the clang linker?

Comment: the linker `ld` is in the `binutils` package. Do you need a different one ?

Comment: I would like to use lld from clang sadly having problems with ld.

Answer (score 0):

lld is not available in any cygwin package

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/lld
Found 0 matches for bin/lld
```

please note that last `Clang` package for `cygwin` is 8.0.1, so several release behind upstream and currently the package is lacking a maintainer

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/clang-src.html

You can report your problems to the cygwin mailing list
https://cygwin.com/lists.html